# How to create an assignment between a type and a generic representation of the type

Tags: c#, asynchronous, generics, promise

I have a coding question which is hard for me to articulate so will show code examples.

code 1:

```
public struct PlayerData {
   public int PlayerScore;
}
```

Code 2:

```
public class Player {
    public PlayerData PD {get; set;}
  .......
}
```

Code 3:

```
public class SaveData {
....
    public PlayerData Load (){
    .....
    }
}
```

Finally, in code 4, I say:

```
_player.PD = _saveData.Load();
```

However the return type in code 3 has changed, and it is now:
Code 3 (changed):

```
     public class SaveData {
....
    public IPromise<PlayerData> Load (){
     ......
     return Promise<PlayerModelDto>.Resolved(dt);
    }
}
```

Now I still need to write:

```
 _player.DP = _saveData.Load();
```

But get an error "Cannot convert "IPromise(PlayerData) to PlayerData"

How can I assign the struct in the IPromise<>  scope to a class with a property of this struct?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the interface definition for `IAsyncLoad<T>`? I'm going to guess there's a `Result` property which returns your `T`. ie a PlayerData struct. You might want to look up `async` and `await` as well.

Comment: Is `IAsynchLoad` your own interface?  Because I cannot find it in the .Net libraries.  If it's your own interface, then you will need to add a property to it to expose its PlayerData object.

Comment: Hi @RBarryYoung I've edited my question - the interface is IPromise interface from RealSeriousGames library, promises for unity. Thanks for pointing out the issue of not using an actual library

Comment: @ZahirJacobs please see the edited question to answer your comment

Comment: The question lacks sufficient detail to provide a useful answer. Some notes though: while you write _"to be equal to"_, it appears what you _really_ want is an _assignment_. While the operators are similar, it's _critical_ for the purpose of expressing your question accurately that you do not confuse _equality_ with _assignment_. They are two completely different things. Second, based on the name `IPromise`, it appears that there's some sort of asynchrony being introduced here. If that's the case, then you will have to adjust your code to accommodate that. The usual C# idiom here would ...

Comment: ... be based on `Task`, which is the .NET equivalent of a "promise" or a "future" (terms that are often used in other contexts to describe the same thing), and you would use the `await` operator to introduce asynchronous waiting for the resolution/completion of the `Task`. In the context above, it's not clear what `JsonUtility`, `Promise`, etc. are. Your question isn't really about the C# language and the error message you're getting, but rather is really about how to use those third-party types and objects. Please improve the question.

Comment: The answers basically the same: you need to look at what that interface exposes to see if you can get to your object.  The only definition for it that I could find was [here](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:mDEBIXBWzYUJ:https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/C-Sharp-Promise/blob/master/src/Promise_NonGeneric.cs+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us), but that is NOT a generic interface.

Comment: OK, I did find the doc [here](https://github.com/Real-Serious-Games/C-Sharp-Promise/blob/master/src/Promise.cs) but as far as I can tell from that, the only place that it is stored is into `.resolveValue` of the `Promise` object but that's a private property.  You'll have to change some other code to grab it *before* it gets passed to the Promise asynch loader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this paradigm but reading the documentation something like

```
_saveData.Load()
.Then(pd => _player.DP = pd);
```

should work.